# Xamarin.IOs Error: Inconsistency between the local app and the remote build

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.IOs project which I code in Visual Studio 2017 for Windows and debug on a real device connecting to a *Mac Build Host* via the **Pair to Mac** tool of Visual Studio.

But I get this error when I try to run my Xamarin.IOs application,

```
An inconsistency between the local app and the remote build has been detected for <App Name>. Please rebuild the application and try again. Check the logs for more details
```

Neither of these solved the problem,

- Rebuilding the application and running again
- Clean the project, build it and running again
- Clean the project, deleting the bin and obj folders, build it and running again

Comment: Try to restart your Mac.

Comment: You don't need to restart the Mac. The answer given below would just solve you the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this error occurs, you have to simply **disconnect your *Mac Build Host*** and then **reconnect to that *Mac Build Host***. Then just try to run the application on the device, it would work!

### Image Guide

[image: Re-connecting to a Mac Build Host]

- **A:** Open **Pair to Mac** window to connect to a *Mac Build Host*
- **B:** The connected *Mac Build Host*
- **C:** Right click and Disconnect this *Mac Build Host*, then connect to it again

Now if you run the application it would deploy to the device without any issues.

**Note:** Connecting To Mac tutorial
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/